# How to get value from emit event without v-on directive?

Tags: vue.js

I have two components: Parent and Child.

In Child component, I create user event:

```
someMethod() {
    this.$emit('init-event', 100)
}
```

Parent component:

```
getChildEventValue() {
    // how now get value from event 'init-event' without v-on directive in template?
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you try to avoid the v-on directive? If the parent element only uses the emit, there is no way around it. So for a good answer we need to know how the parent in build up in this case

Answer (score 0):

The typical & easy way is to simply use an event bus. There are several different methods to create a global event bus.  In my setup I do it as follows

In the main js...

```
Vue.prototype.$Bus = new Vue();
```

Then in your child component, or a sibling or anywhere really...

```
this.$Bus.$emit('myEvent');
```

Then in your other component listen for the event.  Perhaps on mount hook...

```
mounted(){
        this.$Bus.$on('myEvent', function(){
            console.log('receive the event!')
        } );
    }
```

Comment: By only calling [`$on`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) and never calling [`$off`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-off), you will create a memory leak, as custom event listeners aren't cleaned up by default, and the event bus (and attached listeners) is never garbage collected, make sure to also show the `$off` handling to deregister the event. The only place where this practice is same is in components that are never made more than once (like the global app page)